# Чи існує термін для території західної України схожий на термін "Наддніпрянська Україна" для території східної України?

Tags: терміни

Чи існує термін для території західної України схожий на термін *"Наддніпрянська Україна"* для території східної України? Тобто мається на увазі інший термін віддмінний від терміну *"Галичина"* - традиційного терміну для позначення західної України.

Наприклад історично існують терміни *"Лівобережна Україна"* (східна Україна) vs. *"Правобережна Україна"* (західна Україна), або *"Малоросія"* чи *Мала Русь* (східна Україна) vs. *Червоноросія*, *Червона Русь* чи *Малопольща* (західна Україна) тощо й вони є приблизно рівними термінологічно. То чи є схожий термінологічно еквівалент і для *"Наддніпрянська Україна"* (відмінний від *"Галичина"*)?.

Comment: Гм, а хіба Наддніпрянщина має стосунок до східної України? Я завжди був певен, що це радше середня частина України (біля Дніпра), а східна — це, наприклад, Слобожанщина.

Comment: @Sasha Ні, Наддніпрянщина - це вся східна Україна. Так само як Наддністрянщина - це вся Західна Україна. Див. наприклад працю " Ігнатієнко В. Українська преса (1816-1923 рр.): історико-бібліографічний етюд. Київ: ДВУ. 1926", де Ігнатієнко, окрім іншого, пише таке: " «Українська етнографічна територія в період 1816-1834 рр. (Наддніпрянська та Наддністрянська Україна) належала до двох могутніх монархій того часу: Австро-Угорщини та Росії, які тоді вели боротьбу за ті землі" (дж: https://diasporiana.org.ua/wp-content/uploads/books/13710/file.pdf)

Comment: А центральна Україна тоді як називається? (Якщо ж Ви «східною» Україною називаєте всю Україну окрім західної, то це, мені здається, дуже незвично.)

Comment: @Sasha, немаж "центральної України" з точки зору етнографічних територій України. Є Східна Україна (Наддніпрянщина), Західна України (Наддністрянщина) й етнографічні території поза офіційною територією України (Донщина/Кубанщина)

Comment: Тобто Ви «східною» вважаєте всю Україну, окрім західної? Як на мене, це дуже дивне сприйняття. Чи є хоч одне джерело на таку термінологію?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Термін-еквівалент для території західної України схожий на термін *“Наддніпрянська Україна”* чи *"Наддніпрянщина"* (для території східної України) - це *Наддністрянщина* чи *“Наддністрянська Україна”*.

Так на [сайті НБУВ](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ulib/item/REF0002545) дають таке означення : *Наддніпрянщиня - синонім Галичини. Історико-географічний регіон, що розташований на Західній Україні (в межах українських земель, які були у складі Австро-Угорської імперії: Східна Галичина, Північна Буковина, Закарпаття) у верхній та середній течії та басейні Дністра*.

В тернопільській газеті *Українські вісті* у статті [*Безумство і кириня*](https://zbruc.eu/node/90427) від 28 червня 1919 року анонімний автор писав так:

> Здавалобся що в часі, коли **Галичина** у своім бою з поляками виявила так
> чудові результати, а навпаки **Наддніпрянщина** може в тім самім часі
> виказатися тільки мізерією стратегічного і організаційного
> анальфабетизму, люде доброі волі і здорового розуму повинні
> призадуматися над яркою причиною одного і другого і подумати над
> санацією нездорових умов, які спричинюють невдачу.
>
> Є відомим фактом, що **Наддніпрянщина** стояла перед катастрофою так само,
> як в тім самім часі стояла перед катастрофою **Наддністрянщина**. І тут і
> там була та сама причина. Але **Наддністрянщина** мала своіми провідниками
> людей, вправді не дуже мудрих, але принайменше себе шануючих. Бо вони,
> побачивши, що не доросли до своєі задачі, одні накивали пятами а другі
> зріклися свого уряду і передали керму загроженоі краіни диктаторови,
> чоловікови, якого вони і загал вважав найвідповіднійшим. І нікому не
> прийшло на думку квестіонувати цей факт, тимпаче, що найблищі дні
> показали, що цей "кайзершніт" дав гарні результати. Армія і ціле
> населеннє відчуло тверду руку, замовкли толки сільських фільозофів,
> вихованих у **наддніпрянській школі**, кинуго в кут політику, почалося
> діло.
>
> Не сподобалося це тільки політикам з під прапора "Укр. Козака" [...]
> у замітці п. т. "В Галичині диктатура", вони пишуть: "Населення
> **Галичини** приняло акт диктатури неприхильно і лише боротьба з Поляками і успішний наступ на польськім фронті стали на перешкоді
> правдоподібним ексцесам селянських і робітничих мас".
>
> Мала вас з вашими програмами і періпатетіками — фільозофами
> **Наддністрянщина**, та дополітикувалась до сього, що небудь диктатурського "неюридичного" кайзершніту, а по ній бувби вже сьогодні
> тільки спомин. Наш вояка уподобився **наддніпрянському** і замість
> бити ворога, політикував на печі і матюкав "Украіні і панам" так
> довго, аж ворог забрав йому все а його самого засвербіла спина від
> польського нагая. І він волів сю спину підставити під пястук
> "юридично" не оправданого диктатора, а грудь під кулю невмолимого
> ворога. І сталось чудо... Докажіть ви, панове теоретики і сторожі
> прогресівних програм, своіми впертими партізанськими фокусами того
> самого чуда, а **Наддністрянщина** як стій скине зі себе ярмо
> диктатури і кинеться в обійми вашого моря тьми, без лиману і пристані,
> які бодай в далекій будуччині подзвалиб надію на спочинок і ратунок.
> Бо і в краіні диктатора живуть люде, які кушали з дерева
> европейськости і поступовости.

Answer (score 4):

Коротка відповідь: однозначного терміну, певно, не існує. Натомість, існує багато топонімів для менших за розмірами регіонів України.

Ґуґлопошук за терміном «[історико-географічні регіони україни](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%96+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8+%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8)» дає кілька цікавих сайтів, в тому числі [офіційних](http://phm.gov.ua/?p=98220), з гарними мапами регіонів.

[image: Етнографічні регіони України]

Comment: Певно що карта вгорі трохи не відповідає сучасним використанням термнів: для прикладу коли історики кажуть "Галичина", то вони мають на увазі на малюсіньку територію навколо Львова (як показано на карті) а усю Західну Україну (див. наприклад праці Ярослава Грицака: https://zbruc.eu/node/78028 Ярослав ГРИЦАК: “Галичина має дуже сильну цивілізаційну місію”.

п.с. Я взагалі то я на 100% впевнений що термін-еквівалент для західної України схожий на Наддніпряснька Україна існує - я його навіть знаходив пару років тому у галицьких виданнях (чи то ЛНВ) але забув.

Comment: @piznajko, так, навіть на сайті за посиланням є кілька мап, і усі суперечать одна одній. Там мало не усі регіони по-різному зображаються на різних мапах. Думаю, це їхня спільна властивість.

Comment: О знайшов! Це Наддністрянщина!